# FAST for Sharepoint 2010: crawled pipeline properties showing up in logs but not in search results

Tags: sharepoint-2010, pipeline, fastsearch

I have some content that contains dates I have to format. I'm using pipeline extensibility to get these dates from type "text" to type "datetime". I'm using three different sharepoint environments. The development and integration environments have a single content, index, and admin server. The production environment has one 4 index servers, 1 admin server, and 2 content servers. The dates are properly changed and show up in both dev and int. However, in prod the dates do not show up in the logs. When turning on pipeline logging in prod, the correct output shows up, though dates still do not show in the search results. The logs appear in 2 of the index servers and the admin server.

Is there a reason why this wouldn't happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipeline extensibility xml needed to be deployed to both the content servers and the admin servers. After I added the pipeline-extensibility.xml to each of my 4 content servers and my admin server, the dates appeared in the search results.